# Trouble separating three divs in horizontal rows

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am still getting the hang of CSS/HTML markup. In working on a class project to mock up a site UI, I am working on a profile page but can't get the bio text to not wrap up and around the other contents. I just want each component of the profile group to be in a separate box above the others. Below is a screenshot of what is produced by the code at the bottom. Any advice?

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxYSR.png)

Profile.aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">
<div class="content">
    <div class="pane-left">
        <div class="profile-group">
            <div class="pic">
                <img src="img/profile-pic.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="profile photo" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="name">
                <h1>Cody Hunsberger</h1>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="bio">
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                <p>Ants are social insects of the family Formicidae. Like wasps and bees, ants are in the order Hymenoptera. There are about 22,000 species of ants. More than 12,500 have been classified. They have a thin waist and elbowed antennae. Ants form colonies that vary greatly in size. Some species have a few dozen predatory individuals living in small natural cavities. Some highly organised colonies may cover large territories and have millions of individuals. Ants are usually small, but can carry the weight of twenty ants. Worker ants carry food back to the colony so that other ants and the queen can eat. The following account is mainly about ants which live in large colonies.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="pane-right">
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <p>&nbsp</p>
        <strong>College</strong>
        <p>Science and Technology</p>
        <strong>Major</strong>
        <p>Information Science and Technology</p>
        <strong>GPA</strong>
        <p>4.0</p>
        <strong>Enrollment Status</strong>
        <p>Full-Time</p>
        <strong>Credits Earned</strong>
        <p>120</p>
        <strong>Expected Graduation Date</strong>
        <p>Spring 2018</p>
        <strong>Email Address</strong>
        <p>tuf09651@temple.edu</p>
        <strong>Phone</strong>
        <p>(555) 555-5555</p>
        <p>&nbsp</p>
        <h3>Application History</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Administrator</th>
                <th>Term</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>View</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rose McGinnis</td>
                <td>Spring 2018</td>
                <td><span class="label label-warning">Under Review</span></td>
                <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rose McGinnis</td>
                <td>Fall 2017</td>
                <td><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rose McGinnis</td>
                <td>Spring 2017</td>
                <td><span class="label label-danger">Denied</span></td>
                <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
    .pane-left, .pane-right {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.pane-left {
    float: left;
}

.profile-group {
    text-align: right;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 125px;
}

.pane-left > pic > img {
    float: right;
    margin: 100px;
}

.pic, .name, .bio {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.bio > h3 {
    color: black;
    float: right;
}

.name > h1 {
    color: black;
    float: right;
}

.pane-right {
    float:right;
}

.content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;

}

.footer > p {
    color: #b2101f;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a:hover  {
    color: red;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #b2101f;
}

.navbar-default {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    color: #aa0000;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

tr {
    width: 25%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Ended up using the col class for Bootstrap by making it div content > div pane left > div class="row col-md-12" and that resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mf50ed3m/)

I added the following code to the content `div` to align the divs and removed     `display: inline-block;` and float tags as they were making things messy.

```
margin: 0 auto;  
display: flex;  
justify-content: center;
```

---

```css
.content {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
.pane-left, .pane-right {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.profile-group {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 125px;
}

.pane-left > pic > img {
    margin: 100px;
}

.pic, .name, .bio {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.bio > h3 {
    color: black;
}

.name > h1 {
    color: black;
    float: right;
}

.content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;

}

.footer > p {
    color: #b2101f;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a:hover  {
    color: red;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #b2101f;
}

.navbar-default {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    color: #aa0000;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

tr {
    width: 25%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="pane-left">
        <div class="profile-group">
            <div class="pic">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" width="100px" height="100px" alt="profile photo" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="name">
                <h1>Cody Hunsberger</h1>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="bio">
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                <p>Ants are social insects of the family Formicidae. Like wasps and bees, ants are in the order Hymenoptera. There are about 22,000 species of ants. More than 12,500 have been classified. They have a thin waist and elbowed antennae. Ants form colonies that vary greatly in size. Some species have a few dozen predatory individuals living in small natural cavities. Some highly organised colonies may cover large territories and have millions of individuals. Ants are usually small, but can carry the weight of twenty ants. Worker ants carry food back to the colony so that other ants and the queen can eat. The following account is mainly about ants which live in large colonies.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="pane-right">
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <p>&nbsp</p>
        <strong>College</strong>
        <p>Science and Technology</p>
        <strong>Major</strong>
        <p>Information Science and Technology</p>
        <strong>GPA</strong>
        <p>4.0</p>
        <strong>Enrollment Status</strong>
        <p>Full-Time</p>
        <strong>Credits Earned</strong>
        <p>120</p>
        <strong>Expected Graduation Date</strong>
        <p>Spring 2018</p>
        <strong>Email Address</strong>
        <p>tuf09651@temple.edu</p>
        <strong>Phone</strong>
        <p>(555) 555-5555</p>
        <p>&nbsp</p>
        <h3>Application History</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Administrator</th>
                <th>Term</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>View</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rose McGinnis</td>
                <td>Spring 2018</td>
                <td><span class="label label-warning">Under Review</span></td>
                <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rose McGinnis</td>
                <td>Fall 2017</td>
                <td><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rose McGinnis</td>
                <td>Spring 2017</td>
                <td><span class="label label-danger">Denied</span></td>
                <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's making things wrap are the `float:right` in `.bio > h3` and `.name > h1`

Get rid of those.